# I am trying to upgrade my script from Cloudera hbase 4(CDH4) version to (CDH5)

Tags: ruby, hadoop, cloudera

```
def getRegions(config, servername) 
  connection = HConnectionManager::getConnection(config)
  parts = servername.split(',')
  puts parts
  rs = connection.getHRegionConnection(parts[0], parts[1].to_i)
  return rs.getOnlineRegions()
end
```

I am trying to make this code compatible with CDH5. I have looked into CDH5 library but unable to find exact solution.

I am using 
   `connection = ConnectionFactory::createConnection(config)` which returns Connection object.

I want list of onlineRegions on given server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look the following api's

[Admin.html#getClusterStatus()](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#getClusterStatus())

[ClusterStatus.html#getServers()](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/ClusterStatus.html#getServers())

[Admin.html#getOnlineRegions(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ServerName)](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Admin.html#getOnlineRegions(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ServerName))

Note : In older versions, Some of the `Admin` functions live in `HBaseAdmin` class. (Rest of the usage should be same/similar)

Hopefully, that should help you.